# TypeError: string indices must be integers - Python3 Dictionary

Tags: python

I am trying to use an online compiler to run my code but it throws the same error of: string indices must be integers. When I run it locally in a jupyter nb, I do not get this error.

What is the program expecting?
`
import json

```
def solution(content):
    content = json.loads(json.dumps(content))
    sections = {x["Index"] for x in content['Page_limit']} -IT BREAKS HERE!


Console Output:
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "main.py", line 12, in <module>
    res = solution(inp.postcontentstring)
  File "/usercode/solution.py", line 6, in solution
    sections = {x["Index"] for x in content['Page_Limit']} 
  TypeError: string indices must be integers

My json looks like this:
 postitemsonpage = {
      "Page_Limit": [
        {
          "id": "0",
          "index": 0
        },
        {
          "id": "1",
          "index": 2
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "index": 4
        }
      ]}
```

Comment: Ummm. Dict key is `"Page_Limit"` your attempt of getting value is `"Page_limit"` lowercase `l`. Same goes for your index.

Comment: I got `{0, 2, 4}` with run this code.

Comment: The issue is probably outside of the code which is provided. By fixing up the typos in `section()`, then calling `section()` and passing `postitemsonpage`, I get an output `{0, 2, 4}`, with no errors. With that said, I'm voting to close because (1) it's not reproducible, (2) it may be caused by a typo, and (3) if neither, then it would need more details/clarity.

Answer (score 3):

I think your `postitemsonpage` type is string, so you got the `TypeError: string indices must be integers` Error.

code:

```
import json
    
def solution(content):
    content = json.loads(content)
    sections = {x["index"] for x in content['Page_Limit']} #-if you use json.loads(json.dumps(content)) you got a TypeError: string indices must be integers HERE!
    return sections

postitemsonpage = """{
    "Page_Limit": [
        {
            "id": "0",
            "index": 0
        },
        {
            "id": "1",
            "index": 2
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "index": 4
        }
]}
"""
print(solution(postitemsonpage))
```

result:

```
{0, 2, 4}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
import json

def solver(content):
    content = json.loads(json.dumps(content))
    sections = {x["index"] for x in content['Page_Limit']} 

postitemsonpage = {
      "Page_Limit": [
        {
          "id": "0",
          "index": 0
        },
        {
          "id": "1",
          "index": 2
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "index": 4
        }
      ]}
solver(postitemsonpage)
```

You had spelling errors:

```
sections = {x["index"] for x in content['Page_Limit']}
```

and not

```
sections = {x["Index"] for x in content['Page_limit']}
```

**index** is a key which points to an integer whereas **Index** is a string. Hence the error **TypeError: string indices must be integers**.

Comment: that did not solve it. I had it correct in the code but the transfer to stackOF was incorrect. What other reasons could it be?

Comment: In the code example, yes, OP did use the key `"Page_limit"` instead of the key `"Page_Limit"`. However, in the error traceback, the line `sections = {x["Index"] for x in content['Page_Limit']}` indicates that the error was raised, even though the correct key was used.

Comment: What is the error that you are getting if not "TypeError: string indices must be integers"?

Comment: @JacobLee, not just Page_Limit, but index was incorrectly spelled too. It's index and not Index. But in the error message, the person has spelled it as Index.

Comment: @EshaanGupta That wouldn't solve the error. The exception is raised because the index is the wrong data type. In this case, it is most likely attempting to index a list with a string. An incorrect key would raised `KeyError`, not `TypeError`.

Comment: @JacobLee Oh right, that makes sense. Thanks for correcting me!

Answer (score 1):

```
import json

postitemsonpage = {
    "Page_Limit": [
        {
            "id": "0",
            "index": 0
        },
        {
            "id": "1",
            "index": 2
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "index": 4
        }
]}

def solution(content):
    content = json.loads(json.dumps(content))
    sections = {x["index"] for x in content['Page_Limit']}

solution(postitemsonpage)
```

This code seems to work. Perhaps your particular error was in loading this:

> postitemsonpage = {
> "Page_Limit": [
> {
> "id": "0",
> "index": 0
> },
> {
> "id": "1",
> "index": 2
> },
> {
> "id": "2",
> "index": 4
> } ]}

as a string entirely. I don't know, but this works.